# Best way to integrate go with Spark

Tags: go, apache-spark, cassandra

I am running a Cassandra and I am using gocql driver to connect to Cassandra.
Works really good.
I am considering using Apache Spark to analyse on data. 
Should I write a Spark application in Scala or Java and then expose the app to go(somehow) - or how would you do it? 
I am not aware of any go Spark driver.
Any directions and information is welcome.
Regards

Comment: You could extract the data from Cassandra in Avro and load it in Spark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best tool to work on Cassandra data with Scala would be [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/README.md) .

It is so easy and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Running applications that are written in non JVM languages (such as Go) on Spark requires support from Spark itself. The resulting application will most likely be slower and won't have access to all Spark features.

To understand what it takes to run a python Spark app you can read https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals